# Implementing a slider (SeekBar) in Android

Tags: android, slider, touch, seekbar

I want to implement a slider, which is basically two lines, one vertical and one horizontal, crossing where the screen is touched. I have managed to make one but I have to issues:

1. The slider is not very smooth, there is a slight delay when I'm moving the finger
2. If I place two sliders it is not multitouch, and I'd like to use both of them simultaneously

Here is the code:

```
public class Slider extends View {

    private Controller controller = new Controller();
    private boolean initialisedSlider;
    private int sliderWidth, sliderHeight;
    private Point pointStart;
    private Paint white;
    private int mode;

    final static int VERTICAL = 0, HORIZONTAL = 1, BOTH = 2;

    public Slider(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);    
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Slider(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);     
        setFocusable(true);    
        pointStart = new Point();
        initialisedSlider = false;   
        mode = Slider.BOTH;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(!initialisedSlider) {
            initialisedSlider = true;
            sliderWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
            sliderHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

            pointStart.x = (int)(sliderWidth/2.0);
            pointStart.y = (int)(sliderHeight/2.0);
            controller = new Controller(pointStart, 3);

            white = new Paint();
            white.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        }

        canvas.drawLine(controller.getCoordX(),0,
                        controller.getCoordX(),sliderHeight, 
                        white);
        canvas.drawLine(0, controller.getCoordY(), 
                        sliderWidth, controller.getCoordY(), 
                        white);

    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction();     
        int X = (int)event.getX(); 
        int Y = (int)event.getY(); 
        switch (eventaction) { 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(isInBounds(X,Y)) {
                updateController(X, Y);
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(isInBounds(X,Y)) {
                updateController(X, Y);
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(isInBounds(X,Y)) {
                updateController(X, Y);
            }
            break;
        }
        invalidate();  
        return true; 
    }

    private boolean isInBounds(int x, int y) {
        return ((x<=(sliderWidth)) && (x>=(0)) 
                 && (y<=(sliderHeight)) && (y>=(0)));
    }
    private void updateController(int x, int y) {
        switch(mode) {
        case Slider.HORIZONTAL:
            controller.setCoordX(x);
            break;
        case Slider.VERTICAL:
            controller.setCoordY(y);
            break;
        case Slider.BOTH:
            controller.setCoordX(x);
            controller.setCoordY(y);
            break;
        }
    }

    private class Controller {
        private int coordX, coordY;
        Controller() {

        }
        Controller(Point point, int width) {
            setCoordX(point.x);
            setCoordY(point.y);
        }
        public void setCoordX(int coordX) {
            this.coordX = coordX;
        }
        public int getCoordX() {
            return coordX;
        }
        public void setCoordY(int coordY) {
            this.coordY = coordY;
        }
        public int getCoordY() {
            return coordY;
        }
    }
}
```

And the XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <com.android.lasttest.Slider 
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="100dp" 
        android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    <com.android.lasttest.Slider 
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="150dp" 
        android:layout_height="150dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    <com.android.lasttest.Slider 
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="200dp" 
        android:layout_height="200dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Android provides slider which is horizontal

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html

and implement OnSeekBarChangeListener

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html

If you want vertical Seekbar then follow this link

- http://hoodaandroid.blogspot.in/2012/10/vertical-seek-bar-or-slider-in-android.html

Answer (score 34):

## How to implement a SeekBar

[image]

### Add the SeekBar to your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Notes

- `max` is the highest value that the seek bar can go to. The default is `100`. The minimum is `0`. The xml `min` value is only available from API 26, but you can just programmatically convert the `0-100` range to whatever you need for earlier versions.
- `progress` is the initial position of the slider dot (called a "thumb").
- For a vertical SeekBar use `android:rotation="270"`.

### Listen for changes in code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvProgressLabel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // set a change listener on the SeekBar
        SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);

        int progress = seekBar.getProgress();
        tvProgressLabel = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tvProgressLabel.setText("Progress: " + progress);
    }

    SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // updated continuously as the user slides the thumb
            tvProgressLabel.setText("Progress: " + progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // called when the user first touches the SeekBar
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // called after the user finishes moving the SeekBar
        }
    };
}
```

Notes

- If you don't need to do any updates while the user is moving the seekbar, then you can just update the UI in `onStopTrackingTouch`.

### See also

- [SeekBar Tutorial With Example In Android Studio](http://abhiandroid.com/ui/seekbar)

Comment: A note on vertical seekbar. If you want to avoid sizing problems, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51728247/6423246

Answer (score 7):

For future readers!

Starting from [material components android 1.2.0-alpha01](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.2.0-alpha01), you have `slider` component

ex:

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:valueFrom="20f"
        android:valueTo="70f"
        android:stepSize="10" />
```

---

- [Release notes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.2.0-alpha01)
- [Material Design Spec](https://material.io/components/sliders)
- [Docs](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Slider.md)