# Vertical Seekbar in Android

Tags: android, seekbar

I am working on a Player and I want to use Vertical Seekbar to control volume level. Can anybody tell me how to align seekbar vertically, If you have some code it would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a vertical SeekBar in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333658/how-to-make-a-vertical-seekbar-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good code to align seek-bar vertically:
[Vertical Seekbar](http://560b.sakura.ne.jp/android/VerticalSlidebarExample.zip)

Answer (score 1):

> I've made a vertical SeekBar by overriding the onDraw method and flipping it 90 degrees

**VerticalSeekBar**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

/*@Override
    public synchronized void setProgress(int progress)  // it is necessary for calling setProgress on click of a button
    {
        super.setProgress(progress);
        onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0); 
    }*/

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        c.rotate(-90);
        c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);

        super.onDraw(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isEnabled()) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
                onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Use it in your XML layout:

```
<yourPackage.name.VerticalSeekBar
  android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="200dp"
  />
```

> For API 11 and later, can use seekbar's XML a`ttributes(android:rotation="270")` for vertical effect.

```
<SeekBar
android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:rotation="270"/>
```

Comment: But XML attribute ```rotation``` will give undesired effect. Only your view's content is rotated

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar:verticalseekbar:0.7.2'
}
```

Layout XML

```
<!-- This library requires pair of the VerticalSeekBar and VerticalSeekBarWrapper classes -->
<com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp">
    <com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/mySeekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        app:seekBarRotation="CW90" /> <!-- Rotation: CW90 or CW270 -->
</com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper>
```

Java code

```
public class TestVerticalSeekbar extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SeekBar mseekbar = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_vertical_seekbar);

        mseekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mySeekBar);

        mseekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progressChanged = 0;

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                progressChanged = progress;
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seek bar progress:" + progressChanged,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```