# Seekbar, setting progress dynamically creating UI issue

Tags: android, seekbar

I have used custom vertical seekbar in my app, except of one thing everything is working fine. Whenever setting progress dynamically using the below snippet that problem arises,

```
seekbar.setProgress(50);
```

Please refer the screenshot, that is what the output i'm getting...

[image]

Thump position not adjusting properly.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the maximum value you set for seekbar??

Comment: can you post some more code of your seekbar

Comment: I read anytime about an issue on SeekBar. Before setting Your max Value to 100, set it to 0 like seekBar.setMax(0), then seekBar.setMax(100);

Answer (score 1):

You must be get your problem solve  
[Vertical Seekbar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212566/vertical-seekbar-in-android)

Best of luck!