# Custom thumb for a seekbar in Android

Tags: android, seekbar, custom-selectors

I want to create a custom thumb for seekbar that should look like this:

[image]

One solution could be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar), where png pictures are used to draw the thumb.

I believe that it should be possible to use xml only, since it is very similar to this thumb:

thumb.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <size android:height="30dp" android:width="30dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="18dp" android:color="#882EA5DE"/>
    <solid android:color="#2EA5DE" />
    <corners android:radius="1dp" />

</shape>
```

[image]

Just need to add second border (white stroke around), so that I can skip to manage all that pictures for different screen resolutions (hdpi/mdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi).

I have tried different combination with shapes "oval" and "ring", but could not get the result required. How can you make it?

Answer (score 1):

I could not manage to find a solution with just xml, that is why I used a picture to solve this, with a little help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699951/changing-size-of-seekbar-thumb/18559778#18559778):

1. Created an image of the thumb `seekbar_thumb_icon.png`  and saved it in different resolutions in `res/drawable-*` maps (hdpi/mdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi).
2. Specified "android:thumb="@layout/seekbar_thumb" for SeekBar:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<item>
<shape>
    <size
        android:height="30dp"
        android:width="30dp" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/balance_icon_48px"/>

</layer-list>
```

[image]

Other styles:

```
<SeekBar
android:id="@+id/seekbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:progressDrawable="@layout/seekbar_style"
android:thumb="@layout/seekbar_thumb" />
```

seekbar_style.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@layout/seekbar_background" />

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@layout/seekbar_progress" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

seekbar_background.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:shape="line">

   <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#868686"/>
   <corners android:radius="1dp" />
</shape>
```

seekbar_progress.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:shape="line">

   <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ffffff"/>
   <corners android:radius="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Is this working ? android:thumb="@layout/seekbar_thumb" ??