# Vertical seekbar in LinearLayout

Tags: android, progress-bar, seekbar

I have to design vertical seekbar for equalizer app. My design look like this. How can i create this layout. I have created vertical Seekar using this library http://560b.sakura.ne.jp/android/VerticalSlidebarExample.zip

I want to achieve this
[image]

but i got this second image, thumbs are vertical but their progress is showing horizontal

[image]

**xml desing**

```
<com.devmob.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sixty"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />

   <com.devmob.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/twothirty"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />


      <com.devmob.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/nineten"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />

         <com.devmob.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/threek"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />

            <com.devmob.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/fourteenk"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

Edit also tried https://github.com/AndroSelva/Vertical-SeekBar-Android but it shows thumb on the left side, **I want the thumb to be on the progressbar** not left or right.

Comment: You might better implement your own custom seek bar or have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16210097/1457952

Comment: Here you can find a few examples:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18484131/3864698

http://stackoverflow.com/a/8893285/3864698