# Adjusting width & height for view after rotating it by 90 degree in Android

Tags: android, view, rotation, width, programmatically-created

I want to add view & rotate it by 90 degree programmatically, however I can't figure how to set its dimensions properly.

This is my placeholder:

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/placeholder"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_weight="1">
```

And this is how my code looks like:

```
    FrameLayout placeholderView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.placeholder);

    View myView = new View(getApplicationContext());
    myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    myView.setRotation(90);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    myView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    placeholderView.addView(myView);
```

The result is that BOTH width & height get the same value, so the view looks like this:

[image]

While I wanted it to expand on entire height of its parent.

Comment: try below code if it works please up vote thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENTHello can you please try this 
 instead of this:

```
myView.setRotation(90);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
```

try this:

Remove setRotation

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

Comment: I cannot remove setRotation. I know it doesn't make sense to rotate a view as in my code, I just simplified my code to demonstrate the problem I have. I also noticed that FILL_PARENT is deprecated.

Comment: you need vertical view right? i tried on my system working fine and i removed setRotation..even u can try on XML

Comment: I want to use vertical SeekBar so I must rotate it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395064/android-vertical-seek-bar-like-google-play-music-app check this link

Comment: Thanks. I already checked many solutions for vertical SeekBar, none of them worked properly with RTL support. I will check also this one. But I wondered if there's a solution to the general problem I posted, not specfically for SeekBar, it looks like a very basic functionality that should be supported in Android (rotating views), and could be useful also in my case.