# Vertical Drawer on Android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

It's there a way to make a vertical slider on Android?, for example, I want the action bar to be dragged all the way from top to bottom, to show a fragment, pretty much like the notification bar on Android.

Thank you very much

Comment: Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333658/how-to-make-a-vertical-seekbar-in-android

Comment: I don't that's what I'm looking for. I want, for example, to click a button on the action bar, and start sliding it down to the bottom, while doing that on the background a fragment it's being shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always a way ;), but it would take some custom code to do it. I don't really have to much time to write something out for you, but I did find something that may be useful to you. These guys open sourced a slide from bottom to top view like is used in Google Play Music. You can take a look and maybe modify it to slide from top to bottom.

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

There used to be a slidingdrawer view as part of the framework but it's now deprecated. There is however a nice implementation of something similar on github that you can take a look at here:

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Answer (score 0):

Umano's Drawer is dated and limited. You should use a more up-to-date library like https://github.com/drxeno02/androidprojects-book2-slidingdrawer.

This library has no limitations such as only having two children. You can have as many children as you want, and you can set offsets and design your drawer to look anyway you want.