# Vertical Seekbar setProgress not working

Tags: android, progress, seekbar

Seek is not progressing. All seekbar comes to zero but textView shows value properly..

```
choosePreset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {   
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preset_list, null, false);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setView(customView);

        final String[] arr= getEqualizerPresets();

        ArrayAdapter<String> namesAA= new ArrayAdapter<String> ( context,R.layout.myitemlist,arr );
        ListView list = (ListView) customView.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        list.setAdapter(namesAA);

        final AlertDialog ad = builder.create();

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) 
            {
               Toast.makeText(context, "Position"+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               //equalizerWrapper.usePreset((short)arr[position]);

                    for(int v=0;v<eqSeeks.length;v++)
                    {
                    //  equalizerSeeks(v, eqSeeks[v]);
                        final int z = v;
                        eqSeeks[v].post(new Runnable()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                eqSeeks[z].setProgress( EQValues.presetValues[position][z]);
                            }
                        });

                    }

            //   eqSeeks[2].setProgress(150);

               setEqualizerPreset(position);

               ad.dismiss();

            }
        });

        ad.show();
    }
});
```

EQValues.presetValues[position][z] are showing in textView properly but seekbars are not reaching to the progress . I tried many ways but nothing working.

I tried using handler and also use postMethod as shown. But seekBars not reached to values.

**Edit**

i find a [answer](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12945) to add `updateThumb` method to Vertical seekbar but it is also not working. This issue is due to vertical seekbar.

```
public void updateThumb(){
     onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
}
```

And then call update thumb method after setting progress.

```
seekBar.setProgress((int) progress);
seekBar.updateThumb();
```

but this still didn't solve my problem

Comment: updateThumb() solved my problem...

Comment: thanks @Rumit ..it worked for me :)

Comment: Varun Chaudhar you thanks Rumit while code is pasted by me............just kidding

Comment: @Nepster, the solution works. Please post it as an answer so other people can also get the help (y)

Answer (score 5):

> I am facing some other problem. but the given statement works.

**Add updateThumb method in VerticalSeekbar class like**

```
public void updateThumb()
{
     onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
}
```

**And then call update thumb method after setting progress.**

```
seekBar.setProgress((int) progress);
seekBar.updateThumb();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is actually better :

```
@Override
public void setProgress(int progress) {
    super.setProgress(progress);
    onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
}
```

Now `setProgress()` method should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just declared it differently.
Instead of using:

```
VerticalSeekbar mSeekbar;
```

I used:

```
Seekbar mSeekbar;
```

Now mSeekbar.setProgress(progress) works as it should.