# Vertical seekbar with popup window

Tags: android

How to do vertical seekbar with popup window show when seek changes, and popup window show with seek thum.

I want exactly same in image below:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8893285/994926 check this

Comment: I got solution for vertical seekbar but problem is how to show window beside of seek thum with seek change data?

Comment: You can use a library for that or try following [this](http://andygardenforever.blogspot.in/2014/04/create-your-own-custom-seek-bar-with.html)

Comment: @Tushar which library i can use.. can i have link?

Comment: I gave you a link, make a custom class like the one given [here](http://andygardenforever.blogspot.in/2014/04/create-your-own-custom-seek-bar-with.html). This approach is better. In this way you won't even depend on any 3rd party library.

Comment: Did u find any solution ?

Comment: https://github.com/ITheBK/RangeBarVertical this will may be help you

Comment: Or try this https://github.com/ademar111190/android-phased-seek-bar