# How to make a layout for the equalizer?

Tags: java, android, equalizer

This is my code i use to setup a **5 band Equalizer**, but i would like to have a **Layout** which supports the number of equalizer bands supported by the device.

For now i have **hardcoded** the size of **Equalizer bands** because i'm not sure how to create a **Layout** for a non constant value of equalizer bands.

**This is the code i would like to use:**

`equalizer.getNumberOfBands(); //it tells you the number of equalizer in device.`

But what if a device supports **+10 equalizer bands**, how can i fit those **bands** on the screen?

**Code for creating Equalizer**

```
private void setupEqualizer(){

    mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());

    final short lowerEqualizerBandLevel = mEqualizer.getBandLevelRange()[0];
    final short upperEqualizerBandLevel = mEqualizer.getBandLevelRange()[1];

    for (short i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        final short equalizerBandIndex = i;

        int freq_range = mEqualizer.getCenterFreq(equalizerBandIndex);

        verticalSeekbar[i].setMax(upperEqualizerBandLevel - lowerEqualizerBandLevel);
        verticalSeekbar[i].setProgress(mEqualizer.getBandLevel(equalizerBandIndex));

        verticalSeekbar[i].setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
                mEqualizer.setBandLevel(equalizerBandIndex, (short) (progress + lowerEqualizerBandLevel ));
                slider_value[equalizerBandIndex].setText(String.valueOf((progress + lowerEqualizerBandLevel) / 100 + " dB"));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        slider_labels[i].setText(formatBandLabel(freq_range));

        float scale2 = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int dpAsPixels2 = (int) (8*scale2 + 0.5f);

    }
    setupEqSpinner();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you would want to build the layout programmatically.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30118352/3496570

Comment: Yeah i'm doing that, but my question is what would be the recommended way to fit all bands on the screen?

Comment: See https://github.com/Uni-phoenix/MusicPlayerTEMP1/tree/3b0ba3481c346b9f1474d6bfb8a61d0170e59050

Comment: @Henry Check edit, this is what i have now, but what if there are more than 5 bands?

Comment: You can use [**`VerticalSeekBar`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333658/how-to-make-a-vertical-seekbar-in-android)

Comment: @NileshRathod I use seekbars with setRotation

Comment: Damn what's up with the downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to use **Vertical SeekBar**  as told by **Nilesh**

```
equalizer.getNumberOfBands() // it tells the number of equalizer ..
```

Create a `LinearLayout(Horizontal)` and add V**ertical Seekbar** to it  in a for loop  (`numberOfBands`)..

Comment: But if i add rotation to a normal seekbar to make i vertical it wont work? What is the difference?

Comment: No it have issue with the thumb.

Comment: And what if a device has more than say 5 bands? If i make a horizontal linearlayout how would a device with 10+ bands fit on it? That's my question actually.

Comment: add a horizontal ScrollView so LinearLayout can scroll in it. If you satisfy with the answer accept and like it too.