# How to use a vertical seekbar view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-seekbar

```
android:id="@+id/gradientSeekBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:max="8"
android:progress="1"
android:rotation="270"
android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
android:thumbOffset="0dp"
app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="203dp">
```

[My android studio res file for seekbar placment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dnre.png)

*Now, it's not just a vertical seekbar, what I have to do is to place that vertical seekbar on the full right of a mobile screen, as in the picture attached. There are things that we can do like rotating the view but I am not able to adjust the view to the full right of the screen as shown in the picture. Also, I have viewed many top apps on play store that have placed the seek bar in the middle, none of them are able to place the seek bar on the full right. Is there something simple, instead of rotating the view. About the code, I can't use static size because I need to support all size screens.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a vertical SeekBar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333658/how-to-make-a-vertical-seekbar-in-android)

Comment: @IzhanAli nope, I am editing my question to make it more understandable, I have searched for answers, most of them are all about rotating the seek bar view to -90 or 270 degrees, off course then it will be vertically but then the problem will be adjusting the view to the full right of the mobile screen. Implementing the seek bar view and rotate it by 270 or -90 to make it vertical, now it's not possible to align the seekbar to the full right.

Comment: @Muhammad Have you found the answer by chance?