# Change seekbar progress from horizontal to vertical

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have created a vertical seekbar using drawable but thumb still moves in horizontal.

How can I change thumb to move vertically and measure the progress from vertical movement ?

I have checked other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333658/how-to-make-a-vertical-seekbar-in-android) but it rotates my current layout to horizontal, I just want to change the thumb progress vertically.

Here is my layout:

```
 <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/vertical_seekbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:thumbOffset="6dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar_path"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek_bar_thumb"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to rotate it 90 degrees or 270 degrees depending on the result
`android:rotation="90"//or 270`

Comment: Tried, it rotates the whole view, I don't want to rotate view , just want to rotate the movement of thumb progress.