# Custom VerticalSeekBar onSeekBarChangeListener implementation

Tags: seekbar

I have implemented the VerticalSeekBar using this unbelievably simple solution here: [How can I get a working vertical SeekBar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892179/need-working-vertical-seekbar/7341546#7341546)

The problem is, I can't seem to set an onseekbarchangelistener in my UI Activity that uses this class. I can't for the life of me understand how to do this. I can do it from within the VerticalSeekBar class: if I add code inside the onTouch() method, it works.

However I need an onTouch listener in my Activity.

P.S. is there a particular reason why Android doesn't have a native vertical seekbar? Considering most phones are naturally portrait-mode devices, it makes sense to have bars running along the the length rather than the width of the screen. I have tried many VerticalSeekBar solutions from stackoverflow (love this site!), but the only solution that centers my SeekThumb graphic is the link supplied above. I have been working on getting a perfect vertical seekbar for months now. Any help would be a humansend!

Answer (score 1):

in VerticalSeekBar class, comment out this whole part:

```
@Override
public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnSeekBarChangeListener mListener) {
  this.myListener = mListener;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead you can do this

```
SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.your.id);
sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```

Eclipse would underline it and ask you to implement onseekbarchangelistener, you do that and implement the methods and you are good to go

Good Luck !