# Add seek bar on map using Map API V2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working on a application in which i am using Google Map Api V2, the map is successfully loaded, also i have put markers on it but now when i tried to add a seek bar on my map its not showing it on map's surface, actually i want to give a feature in which a user can increase and decrease the radius of circle using seek bar, but when i add that seek bar through XML its not showing me the seek bar,

my XML is like that :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg_views"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="StreetView" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_satellite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Satellite" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_terrain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Terrian" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rg_views" >

        <fragment
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="-30dp"
            android:max="400"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:progress="100"
            android:rotation="270" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

if anyone knows how to place button, seek bar on map's surface then please help me

thanks

Comment: try uploading your XML file content, that would help find the root of your problem

Comment: Hi @Noloxs, i have added my xml please reply....

Comment: I assume it's the problem with rotation. I tried different implementations, but never made it work vertically. Try without rotation and see if it shows up.

Comment: @Doctoror Drive yeah its working thanks but why it is not showing when  its vertical i cannot see any logic behind it ......

Comment: its ok for u now @Doctoror Drive............

Comment: Hey Salman khan, I am also looking for a feature where the user can set the seekbar and change radius of map area. Did you got it working, I would appreciate if you can share the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SeekBar is made for being horizontal. Rotating it will make problems for it to show properly without code modification. You can try examples of vertical SeekBar implementations, but non of them worked for me well.

[How can I get a working vertical SeekBar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892179/how-can-i-get-a-working-vertical-seekbar-in-android)

http://hackskrieg.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/working-vertical-seekbar-for-android/