# Vertical Seekbar with correct min and max values?

Tags: max, seekbar, min

this one [How can I get a working vertical SeekBar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892179/how-can-i-get-a-working-vertical-seekbar-in-android) doesn t work for me. By turnig the bar to the bottom or top the max and min values are higher than setmax() and lower than 0 - it was neagtiv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here http://hackskrieg.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/working-vertical-seekbar-for-android/.

simply replace the class complete with this new class. Thanks to techn1x.