# Vertical volume slider

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a vertical volume level bar with a slider. The users can change the volume by moving the slider up or down. The volume can also be manually set. I only have not idea how to create a layout component which will fit my requirements. Does anyone have tip where to start? I'm aware that you can create [custom views in Android](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html). I already did this for some very basic components.

I am trying to create a layout component which looks like on of these images:

[image: Slider 1]

[image: Slider 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 -you can achieve it by creating "Custom SeekBar"
  There are several sample project available in market
```

[1.Custom Seekbar](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/)   [2.Custom Seekbar](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-use-and-custom-seekbar-in-android.html)

Then make it [Vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7341546/1339473)