# Vertical Seekbar and problems with R / android.R

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm trying to get a vertical Seekbar in my app and I've found sort of a solution here: [Modifying the Android seekbar widget to operate vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631238/modifying-the-android-seekbar-widget-to-operate-vertically/3349669#3349669)

I've downloaded the [VerticalSeekbarExample](http://560b.sakura.ne.jp/android/VerticalSlidebarExample.zip) and it looks good but how do I import it to my app? If I drag the source into my project i get a bunch of errors relating to "R"

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project from existing source. If you are getting errors related to the R class, clean and build the project again and make sure that you are importing com.example.R instead of android.R.