# is it possible to make equalizer android

Tags: android

Doing a little search i realized that to make an equalizer. I need to use C or C++ That would also mean that i have to use the NDK to integrate that with my Java code. The question is, how can i make the C and Java code interact with each other. I don't even know C but i really want that equalizer in my music player. Do you guys know of any good C book which is the best for beginners?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be no need to use the NDK. There already is an [Equalizer-Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) in Android, which is also used by the [standard Android Music Player](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music). Also, here is an answer on [how to make the Sliders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022136/how-to-make-scrollable-button-in-android/6022199#6022199)

Comment: is this equalizer class available from 2.2 or only from 2.3.3?

Comment: It's API Level 9, so it's available since Android 2.3

Comment: that's a shame, i want my equalizer to be available from 2.2 How can i achieve that? Using C?

Comment: @LukasKnuth can you please help me.. i dont want equalizer but i just want to show graphics of equalizer like bars moving up and down or heart beat like animation..can you help me ?

Comment: @SwapAndroid I'd say the [`Visualizer`-class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) looks like something you want.

Comment: @LukasKnuth thank you so much .. i got idea now.. but do you know how can i display in bars ..i found code look like heartbeats but do you know anything for bar..

Comment: @SwapAndroid depends on the kinds of effects you want. If it's simple, create some Bitmaps and draw them on a [`SurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html). If you need something more fancy, have a look at [OpenGL ES](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a list of great books. Do a search through there and see what people suggest.

[SO list of books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)

Answer (score 0):

you'll also need to get familiar with the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) for making the java portion of your app utilize c or c++ methods.