# How to implement a trackbar

Tags: android

Is there anyway to implement something like a trackbar on android, so I can explicity specify the values and select it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i recall there were some tutorials on how to add one to a preference activity, so it is certanly possible, other than that there is the seekbar component in the sdk. you can even drag it in layout with the GUI tool.

if you have seen the media player controls and other similar things that can be added that is also a possibility although i don't know if those can be modified.

see this for customizing the seek Bar:

[seekBar](http://www.anddev.org/seekbar_progressbar_customizing-t6083.html)

also this thing about vertical seekbar can be helpfull:

[Vertical seekBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631238/modifying-the-android-seekbar-widget-to-operate-vertically)

Answer (score 3):

What you are you looking for is the SeekBar

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html