# Android SeekBar doesn't refresh after dynamically setting max value with setMax

Tags: android, seekbar

I am using the stock SeekBar component to navigate through a set of ViewPagers and it's working quite fine. Only problem is that when the data changes, I have to dynamically change the max value of the SeekBar via setMax(int value). When I do that, the SeekBar does not get updated until I navigate to a new page. I have a hacky fix in place where I do this, to force a onProgressChanged:

```
seekBarVP.setProgress(focusedPage+1);
seekBarVP.setProgress(focusedPage-1);
seekBarVP.setProgress(focusedPage);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Question is some months old now but I'll answer anyway because searching for this problem brought me here.

Answer is there is actually a bug in Android. It seems to be fixed on my 3.2.1 tablet but the bug is present on my 2.3.6 phone. The bug is in the ProgressBar widget which is a parent of the SeekBar class. Your solution to setting the progress to a bogus value and back is so far the easies workaround I could find.

You will find more detailed information about this bug here:
[android progressBar does not update progress view/drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348032/android-progressbar-does-not-update-progress-view-drawable)

Answer (score 12):

Create updateThumb(); method in VerticalSeekbar

```
public void updateThumb(){
     onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
}
```

And then call update thumb method after setting progress.

```
seekBar.setProgress((int) progress);
seekBar.updateThumb();
```

its work for me in verticalseekbar calss

Comment: worked for holoeverywhere seekbar with android 5.1.1 - however method `onProgressChanged` doesnt work anymore...

Comment: Should invalidate() call fix it too? since it will redraw and remeasure width height? I tried with invalidate() call after setMax() but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

> @saravanan Answer is correct. But should be done in this way.

Solved the issue by overriding setProgress in VerticalSeekbar class.

```
 @Override
    public synchronized void setProgress(int progress) 
    { 
        super.setProgress(progress); 
        onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, I can confirm @saravanan's solution works great with `VerticalSeekBar`, but there is another way (better imho) to solve it, i.e. the answer of @TechnIx found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631238/modifying-the-android-seekbar-widget-to-operate-vertically).

The basic solution is using this function in your VerticalSeekBar class:

```
public synchronized void setProgressAndThumb(int progress) {
    setProgress(getMax() - (getMax()- progress));
    onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight() , 0, 0); }
```

Hope it helps!