# SeekBar not setting actual progress. SetProgress() not working on early Android Versions

Tags: android, seekbar

I have an app where I want to set the progress of a specific SeekBar based upon a value retrieved from a web service. However when I use SetProgress(int) only the "seeker" of the SeekBar gets set. The bar does not get "filled" out as expected.

This is what it looks like :

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this issue ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Android 2.3.5.  Did you find a solution?  I am calling setMax() before calling setProgress().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set max value first and then set the progress.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out this is a bug in Android.  See also:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12945

[Android SeekBar doesn't refresh after dynamically setting max value with setMax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438198/android-seekbar-doesnt-refresh-after-dynamically-setting-max-value-with-setmax)

[android progressBar does not update progress view/drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348032/android-progressbar-does-not-update-progress-view-drawable)

A workaround is to do something like setMax(0) followed by setMax(max) and then setProgress().