# Vertical Seekbar fill parent won't work

Tags: android, seekbar

I finally got the vertical seekbar sample working from

[How can I get a working vertical SeekBar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892179/need-working-vertical-seekbar/7966499#7966499)

(thanks for that Paul Tsupikoff)

But i now have a vertical linear layout with only the vertical seekbar implemented that looks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <com.example.layouts.VerticalSeekbar 
           android:id="@+id/v_seekbar" 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Instead of drawing the vertical seekbar until the end of the screen it draw's it with no limit. maybe it's something in the working Vertical SeekBar class that is responsible for this behavior? ( [How can I get a working vertical SeekBar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892179/need-working-vertical-seekbar/7966499#7966499) )
Or is there something i'm missing?

Update:
changing the layout_height to more than 40dip also makes it draw the vertical seekbar out of the screen with no limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got the vertical seekbar working only with diffrent classes derived from [Modifying the Android seekbar widget to operate vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631238/modifying-the-android-seekbar-widget-to-operate-vertically) (thanks to pengwang) here are his zip files for the solution.

http://560b.sakura.ne.jp/android/VerticalSlidebarExample.zip

These vertical seekbars can now do fill_parent