# android seek bar customization,

Tags: android

I need to customize a seek bar in such a way that, at pre determined time say , 30sec, I should have a dot on the seek bar.
This duration varies for each and every video, so how to I place a dot point on the seek bar at a particular second

Comment: Have you tried to creat custom view?

Comment: @sandrstar custom view for seek bar? a class extending seek bar? Have no much idea as how to place these dots. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here're some possibilities:

1. Put 'dot' view just above `SeekBar` one. Will not explain it here in details, because it's trivial android-layout task;
2. Extend `SeekBar`, like the following (refer to [this good explanation about custom views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608464/android-custom-ui-with-custom-attributes)):

   ```
   /**
    * Seek bar with dots on it on specific time / percent
    */
   public class DottedSeekBar extends SeekBar {

       /** Int values which corresponds to dots */
       private int[] mDotsPositions = null;
       /** Drawable for dot */
       private Bitmap mDotBitmap = null;

       public DottedSeekBar(final Context context) {
           super(context);
           init(null);
       }

       public DottedSeekBar(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
           init(attrs);
       }

       public DottedSeekBar(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyle);
           init(attrs);
       }

       /**
        * Initializes Seek bar extended attributes from xml
        *
        * @param attributeSet {@link AttributeSet}
        */
       private void init(final AttributeSet attributeSet) {
           final TypedArray attrsArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.DottedSeekBar, 0, 0);

           final int dotsArrayResource = attrsArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.DottedSeekBar_dots_positions, 0);

           if (0 != dotsArrayResource) {
               mDotsPositions = getResources().getIntArray(dotsArrayResource);
           }

           final int dotDrawableId = attrsArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.DottedSeekBar_dots_drawable, 0);

           if (0 != dotDrawableId) {
               mDotBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), dotDrawableId);
           }
       }

       /**
        * @param dots to be displayed on this SeekBar
        */
       public void setDots(final int[] dots) {
           mDotsPositions = dots;
           invalidate();
       }

       /**
        * @param dotsResource resource id to be used for dots drawing
        */
       public void setDotsDrawable(final int dotsResource) {
           mDotBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), dotsResource);
           invalidate();
       }

       @Override
       protected synchronized void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
           super.onDraw(canvas);

           final int width = getMeasuredWidth();
           final int step = width / getMax();

           if (null != mDotsPositions && 0 != mDotsPositions.length && null != mDotBitmap) {
               // draw dots if we have ones
               for (int position : mDotsPositions) {
                   canvas.drawBitmap(mDotBitmap, position * step, 0, null);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Don't forget about custom attrs in `res/values/attrs.xml`:

   ```
   <resources>
       <declare-styleable name="DottedSeekBar">
           <attr name="dots_positions" format="reference"/>
           <attr name="dots_drawable" format="reference"/>
       </declare-styleable>
   </resources>
   ```

   And using the following code:

   ```
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   final DottedSeekBar bar = (DottedSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

   bar.setDots(new int[] {25, 50, 75});
   bar.setDotsDrawable(R.drawable.dot);
   ```

   with main.xml layout:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.TestApp"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <com.example.TestApp.DottedSeekBar
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/seekBar" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

   or just single main.xml:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.TestApp"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <com.example.TestApp.DottedSeekBar
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/seekBar"
           custom:dots_positions="@array/dots"
           custom:dots_drawable="@drawable/dot" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

   You could obtain the following image:
   [image]
3. Refer to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631238/modifying-the-android-seekbar-widget-to-operate-vertically) for more ideas;

Regarding putting dots on specific 'time': `SeekBar` is not about time, so it's up to You to provide any time-related logic.

Comment: custom:dots_positions="@array/dots" this line showing error in xml. what should i do now. please help

Comment: Are you sure you have "xmlns:custom=..." in first tag in your xml?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add, I fixed this issue, thanks for prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is completely correct but the onDraw method could have been improved a little.

```
        @Override
        protected synchronized void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            final float width=getMeasuredWidth()-getPaddingLeft()-getPaddingRight();
            final float step=width/(float)(getMax());

            if (null != mDotsPositions && 0 != mDotsPositions.length && null != mDotBitmap) {
                // draw dots if we have ones
                for (int position : mDotsPositions) {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mDotBitmap, position * step, 0, null);
                }
            }
        }
```