# How to add marks on seekbar android on run time?

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

How can i add marks on seekbar like this yellow mark on seekbar in android.

[image]

But i want to to this on run time.

e.g

May be i need to add mark on 10sec and 26sec.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Android SeekBar doesn't have an API for correctly placing marks on the bar.  There is also no way of telling the actual pixel location of various positions on the bar, so you wouldn't want to guess at an overlay position.

Instead, you'll want to implement your own seekbar, maybe copying the Android source code for SeekBar as a starting point, and having it expose an api for attaching a marker at a position.

Comment: can you tell me how can i implement own seek bar for this purpose.Mean do you have any example code for this.?

Comment: I already gave you a first place to look - the Android SeekBar source code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution of this problem on stackoverflow. 
Not perfect but working.

[android seek bar customization,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637925/android-seek-bar-customization)