# How to set a custom seekbar on the default MediaController?

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way of setting a custom seekbar on the default MediaController; preferably without having to completely extend the MediaController.

Following the information on this post:
[android seek bar customization,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637925/android-seek-bar-customization)
I've created a custom seekbar class however I'd like to set that onto the MediaController being used in my VideoPlayerActivity.

Looking at the implementation for the MediaController, it looks like you can retrieve the seekbar Resource using its basic identifier

```
"mediacontroller_progress", "id", "android"
```

Therefore, is it possible to create a unique resourceId and set the MediaController to retrieve this resource instead? If not, then how would one go about setting the seekbar?

Answer (score 0):

So after a week of playing around with this, it seems like the seekbar on the MediaController is not customizable :(. You ***CAN*** however style the drawable used for the progression of the seekbar through the method `setProgressDrawable(Drawable d)`

In order to customize a seekbar, you'll need to extend the seekbar class and create your custom seekbar within a custom view to mimic the playback controls of the `MediaController`.