# how to show tick mark on seek bar for api 23 and less

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display tick mark on discrete seekbar for api lower then 24 , i am able to show tick mark on an above api 24 because the attribute ,

```
android:tickMark="@drawable/tickmark"
```

is introduced in API 24,
please help.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637925/android-seek-bar-customization

Comment: If your `compileSdkVersion` is 24, then you are good, tickmark will be shown on device with API 23.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use app:tickMark instead of android:tickMark

Comment: `android:tickMark` will put the tickmark behind the seekbar, `app:tickMark` will put the tickmark on top of the seekbar (as of API 28)

Comment: pretty weird, actually

Comment: I dunno, I can see uses for both so it's nice to have options for styling.

Comment: @saywhatnow if we need `android:tickmark` -like functionality for pre-23, we can't really do much.

Comment: Good Point, Its not easy to figure out what will be the issue here