# How to display markers for ads in Leanback ExoPlayer seekbar?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I want to display markers for ads in Exoplayer using the Leanback Adapter and Glue. I am using `android.support.v17.leanback.media.PlaybackTransportControlGlue` and `android.support.v17.leanback.media.PlayerAdapter`. See the classes `VideoExampleWithExoPlayerActivity`, `ExoPlayerAdapter` and `VideoMediaPlayerGlue` in [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/tree/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/app/media).

It will be similar to the Youtube ad markers in yellow:
[image: Ad marker]

How do I do it?

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17639132/2581109), resolved my problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17639132/2581109

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android seek bar customization,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637925/android-seek-bar-customization)