# Modification of Leanback Video Player UI

Tags: java, android, android-tv, leanback

I want to modify the Leanback Video Player UI. There are two things I want to change:

1. The `Seekbar` in which I want to to be able to put the cue point markers for ads.
2. I want to change the positions of the buttons and the title and subtitle.

I tried extending the `androidx.leanback.widget.SeekBar` class and modifying it and overriding the `lb_playback_transport_controls_row.xml` file but that class has been marked as `final`. I already have the cue point locations and just need to modify the `Seekbar`.

I don't know which class to extend and modify and which layout file to override to put the poster in.

Comment: For the SeekBar change, it might be useful to refer to this [resolved answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637925/android-seek-bar-customization/17639132#17639132)

Comment: @Tom That doesn't work for the leanback library as the Seekbar in it is final and package-private.

Comment: @khateeb did you get anything for showing controls on various positions?

Comment: Does anyone have found any solution for accessing the seek bar inside the widget?

Comment: [This repository](https://github.com/yuliskov/SmartTubeNext/) contains some modifications to `Seekbar` and other UI elements of leanback video player. Modifications are under [this directory](https://github.com/yuliskov/SmartTubeNext/tree/master/smarttubetv/src/main/java/com/liskovsoft/smartyoutubetv2/tv/ui/mod/leanback). It may give you a clue about how to modify player widgets.